# Printing static content after all content

Tags: css, xslt

I am generating html using XSL at the runtime. My task is to print signature section after all the data is printed. I am printing data like this:
Customer 1 data
Customer 2 data
Customer 3 data
Customer 4 data
Customer 5 data
Customer 2's Signature

Each customer data has id, name, address, etc., upto 5 details per customer.
At the end of all customer data I need to print Customer 2's signature section.
Right now the customer data is running till 3 pages, and owner section is printing in the first page only. But i need Customer 2 at the end of the 3 pages.

Take a look at the sample XML..

```
<t>
<customer/>
<customer/>
<customer/>
<customer/>
<customer/>
</t>
```

I need an output like this

```
  Customer 1 data

  Customer 2 data

  Customer 3 data

  Customer 4 data

  Customer 5 data

  Customer 2' Signature.
```

Comment: It is always good to provide a complete (but small source XML document) and the exact wanted result. Without this any answer is just a guess.

Comment: Sorry :P The original code is production code...cant post it here and I need to resolve the issue early. This is working now. Thank you so much!

Comment: sans481: You are welcome. Even if you can't provide the original XML (quite natural), you still can and should provide realistic examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>

   <xsl:apply-templates mode="sign" select=
   "customer[@id=2]/SignatureSection"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="customer">
 Customer <xsl:value-of select="position()"/> data
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="SignatureSection"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (because the fake XML provided by the lazy OP is useless):

```
<t>
    <customer id="1">
     Some Customer1 Data

     <SignatureSection id="1">
       Signature of Customer1
     </SignatureSection>
    </customer>
    <customer id="2">
     Some Customer2 Data
     <SignatureSection id="2">
       Signature of Customer2
     </SignatureSection>
    </customer>
    <customer id="3">
     Some Customer3 Data
     <SignatureSection id="3">
       Signature of Customer1
     </SignatureSection>
    </customer>
    <customer id="3">
     Some Customer4 Data
     <SignatureSection id="4">
       Signature of Customer4
     </SignatureSection>
    </customer>
    <customer id="5">
     Some Customer5 Data
     <SignatureSection id="5">
       Signature of Customer5
     </SignatureSection>
    </customer>
</t>
```

**produces what we *guess* could be the wanted result**:

```
 Customer 1 data

 Customer 2 data

 Customer 3 data

 Customer 4 data

 Customer 5 data

       Signature of Customer2
```

Comment: This is taking the same page. Signature comes in first page where data is running till 4 pages. Resulting in a overlap of data on first page.

Comment: @sans481: Sorry, I don't understand a single word of your comment and how it is related to this answer. If you have changed the problem (again), please, feel free to ask a new question -- this time try to provide at least the essential data to make this a question that doesn't require guessing.